# Is there a way for a PHP script to know the address of the site that it is used on?

Tags: php

I have a PHP script located on `mysite.org` and I use it to display images on sub sites of `example.com` (like `example.com/foo/bar`, `example.com/foo/another-bar`). I can only post links to that script there.

Tried `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, and `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` but there's no go.

So what i need is some way to know if its used on e.g. example.com/foo/bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for the `Referer` header, which tells you the page that the request for an image came from.

Note that some browsers do not send this header.

Answer (score 0):

just create a test php script containing:

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

It will give you very detailed list of php settings and global variables, the setting that you are looking for is bound to be there.

Answer (score 0):

You need a combination of `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` and `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.  Or maybe I'm misinterpreting the question.  `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` returns the domain name a script is running on.

Answer (score 0):

You may use $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], you can check other variables from the php documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`